# String comparison in db2 table

Tags: sql, db2, string-comparison

New to sql and db2 queries. I have a table that will contain both numbers and alphanumeric values. They column is defined as VARCHAR. I am trying to compare the column with another value (which is more likely numbers only) if they fall within a range.

```
SELECT COL1
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COL1 >= RANGE_START AND COL1 <= RANGE_END;
```

Consider the table contains below values in COL1.

```
106
1000003000
A105
ABCDD

RANGE_START as 1000000000
RANGE_END as 3000000000
```

When I run the query it also gives 1000003000 and 106 as a satisfying condition. Why would it give 106? Any help in this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to use CAST( AS BIGINT) but that fails with invalid character string error.

Comment: If you want to understand why the string '106' is greater than the string '1000000000', try `SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY COL1`.  This comparison is performed in character-sorted order, not numeric order.